# Trimming elments of a list

Tags: python, list

Consider the following code

```
l = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
l1 = []
k = 3
for i in range(len(l)):
  l1.append(l[i][:3])

print(l1)
```

Output is

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

In simple words, I want to trim to a given size, each element of the given list. Can I do it in more compact way?

Comment: @Divakar Actually I mapped by problem on numpy to a toy problem. So, I did it subconsciously.

Comment: `newL = [ n[:3] for n in l ]` would be short

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map`:

```
l1 = list(map(lambda x: x[:3], l))
```

Or list comprehension:

```
l1 = [x[:3] for x in l]
```

As suggested in the comments.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the `list()` call, not a good idea answering questions on my phone :) also, list comprehension is probably more compact.